# ProGuard : Obfuscated jar is not working but un-obfuscated jar is working

Tags: java, spring, maven, proguard, obfuscation

I have one project which is part of another one. I am using **maven** build process to make project's jar. I used **ProGuard** to obfuscate it. I have some controllers which handles UI requests.

**Q. My problem is un-obfuscated jar is working. All controllers are getting hit, but obfuscated jar is not working (none controller gets hit). Whats the issue with obfuscation ?**

My Servlet.XML :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="myPackage.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Sample controller code :

```
package myPackage.controllers.information;

import myPackage.beans.InfoBean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/information")
public class InformationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public return_bean getAllInformation() {
        //some logic
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{infoId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public return_bean updateInformation(@PathVariable String InfoId, @RequestBody InfoBean info) {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

My POM.XML contents related to ProGuard :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <maxMemory>576m</maxMemory>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <!-- File with proguard configuration -->
        <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java7home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java7home}/jre/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My ProGuard.conf file contents :

```
-dontnot
-dontwarn
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-keep public class * { public protected *;}
-keep class myPackage.controllers.** { public protected *;}
-keepattributes SourceFile,Signature,LineNumberTable,Exceptions, *Annotation*
-keepparameternames
-printmapping '${logFilesPath}/${project.artifactId}.log'
```

I checked my obfuscated jar, all annotations are persisted.
Also in my information package I have some other classes which have package level access only. So those are getting obfuscated too. But all my classes which have RequestMappings are public and not getting obfuscated.

**My running environment :**

1) Java 1.7 for my project. But this jar is getting placed in project which is running on Java 1.8

2) ProGuard version : 5.2.1

3) Spring : 4.0.9

4) Jackson : 1.9.11

(*Note* : Un-ofuscated jar is working but obfuscated is not working in above environment)

Comment: Do you receive any errors when the obfuscated jar starts? Are you receiving timeouts?

Comment: no. it just says reading and reading and then preparing output jar. Anything I missed ? Also it takes some jars from .m2 folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I need to add following in ProGuard.conf file

```
-keepdirectories
```

Directory entries are removed by default in obfuscation process. This is done to reduce size of jar. As I use "component-scan" feature of Spring (which may need directory structure) I need to keep it to work properly.

Comment: I just wanted to dive deeper into `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` and guess that your hint saved me a lot of time. Thanks - it works now.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling quite a while trying to figure out the real inner difference between the Proguard output jar and the same jar after extracting and repackaging.