# JPA entities in obfuscated jar not found/loaded by Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, proguard

In have a Spring Boot application, with a JPA entity A with that has relation to an Entity B included in an obfuscated jar.

I'm getting the common "@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on A references an unknown entity: B" error when Hibernate initializes.

The error is strictly produced when I obfuscate the jar with Proguard.

In my proguard configuration I'm already using this to preserve all persistence annotated classes, and runtime annotations:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keep @javax.persistence.* class * {
   *;
}
```

If I decompile the code I see that the JPA annotations are there but the entity is still not found.

I've also tried preserving the whole entity with this:

```
-keep class B
```

But the error persists. I don't know what else is being altered by Proguard in the jar that prevents Hibernate from finding the Entity.

BTW in Spring Boot I'm using the @EntityScan with the explicit package name.

---

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

The solution was to add:

```
-keepdirectories
```

Directory entries are removed by default in obfuscation process to reduce the output jar size. Without the directories Spring Boot was unable to find the entities configured with path scan.

A similar issue was reported and answered here:
[ProGuard : Obfuscated jar is not working but un-obfuscated jar is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669903/proguard-obfuscated-jar-is-not-working-but-un-obfuscated-jar-is-working)

Comment: The solution was to add: -keepdirectories

Comment: Instead of updating the question with your solution, you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding: -keepdirectories